# What are "status" and "results" passed in callback function of google maps?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

[image]Can anyone tell me what are "status" and "results" passed inside "callback" function in the following link? The problem i am facing is, in my map the markers are not being showed. So i guess, there must be some problem with any any of these two arguments. Please do mention if you need any more references.

```
  Link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search
```

P.S. I am using Firebase and implementing Javascript.

Comment: Does your code produce any errors in the console?

Comment: Does your code add any markers to the map? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue

Comment: Actually guys i was able to debug it. It seems that the "**PlacesService** "stuff in the code works only when i include a particular google map library script file in my code. Now, it is working perfectly fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/places-service#PlacesService.nearbySearch), nearbySearch takes a [PlaceSearchRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/places-service#PlaceSearchRequest) and uses a callback function that returns an array of [PlaceResults](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/places-service#PlaceResult) that return details about the POIs and a status of type [PlacesServiceStatus](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/places-service#PlacesServiceStatus) that returns whether the query was successful or not. You can use the [PlaceGeometry](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/places-service#PlaceGeometry) and the icon in the individual PlaceResult to place a [Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/marker#Marker) with the correct icon in your map